# Anonymous variables in Erlang

Tags: variables, erlang

What are the exact differences between underscore variables and a named variable that starts with underscore from the Erlang compiler point of view (apart from adding readability to the code)?

For example are `_` and `_Var` different?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The *don't care* variable `_` is a **VERY SPECIAL** variable which matches anything and is **NEVER** bound to a value. It is used when I know there is something there but I don't care what the value is and I will never use. Seeing `_` is never bound it can not be used in an expression and the compiler flags it as an error.

Variables like `_Var` are perfectly normal variables which you can match against and will be bound to values which means they can be used in expressions. Prefixing a variable with `_` is about *intent*. The compiler normally warns you about a variable which is bound in a pattern but is never used, often a sign of an error. But the compiler does not warn for variables prefixed with `_` like in `_Var`. The intent being that I want to give the variable a name, naming things is good, but that I know I will never use it.

Remember that `_` is really the only special variable and that `_Var` are normal variables and behave as such if used. If you are feeling perverse then you could prefix all your variables with `_` and everything will still work.

Comment: Thanks! This was a through answer.:-)

Answer (score 20):

Let's quote the [doc](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id76122) here:

> The anonymous variable is denoted by underscore (`_`) and can be used
>   when a variable is required but **its value can be ignored**. [...]
>
> Variables starting with underscore (`_`), for example `_Height`, are normal variables, not anonymous: they are however ignored by the compiler **in the sense that they will not generate any warnings for unused variables**.

In other words, you use `_Var` form when you need the matched expression to be matched - but don't want to use it further AND/OR you want show its meaning. And you use `_` variable when neither you nor compiler should care for the expression that will be matched by it.

**Example 1:**

```
member(_, []) -> [].
```

In this function is not quite clear what the first `_` matches. But rewriting it directly, like this:

```
member(Elem, []) -> [].
```

... will generate a warning, if the code is compiled with the flag `warn_unused_vars` set. You still can make you code readable here, though, by using underscored variable:

```
member(_Elem, []) -> [].
```

**Example 2:**

```
{_, _, Some} = {1, 2, 3}
```

This tuple matching will go though quite all right, as the first two elements of tuple will be ignored completely.

```
{_Var, _Var, Some} = {1, 2, 3}
```

This matching will fail, however: though `_Var` won't have to be used, it should be 'filled' with the same value! As 1 is not equal to 2, the condition fails here.

Comment: OK, but is there any reason not to use this kind of variables that their name start with an underscore?

Comment: @AKh_Sw Because you mostly _do_ want compiler warning for unused variables, that's why it exists.

Comment: @AKh_Sw As explained at end of response (example 2) it can create badmatch. Imagine you have a complex code, and after a refactoring you decide to un-use a previously used variable, but this variable occurred several times in this complex code. You just put _ to not use it but it is actually used. Then you could have unexpected badmatch.

Moreover, the need to use those underscore variables to document the code is sometimes considered as a "code smell" and an invitation to simplify it.