# Ejabberd filter_packet clause not firing

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm currently trying to write an ejabberd module but am falling at the first hurdle so assume I am missing something simple.

The aim for the finished module is to inspect a message body and look for a certain term.  If the term is present then the module will drop the message and send a reply to the originator informing them that their message has been dropped due to the violation.  I do not want to just obfuscate the offending term.

I have built a skeleton test module using the 'hello world' example from the [main ejabberd webpages](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/extending-ejabberd/modules/#mod-hello-world) and it works so I seem to be putting things in the right place and compiling them properly.

Taking inspiration from sources such as [mod_pottymouth](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/tree/master/mod_pottymouth) as well as related stack overflow questions such as [Filtering message packet's body in ejabberd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284411/filtering-message-packets-body-in-ejabberd) and [How to filter messages in Ejabberd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939879/how-to-filter-messages-in-ejabberd) (not to mention various blogs and other articles) code along the lines of the following should work as far as I can tell:

```
-module(mod_helloworld).

-behaviour(gen_mod).

-include("logger.hrl").
-include("ejabberd.hrl").

-export([start/2, stop/1, on_filter_packet/1]).


start(_Host, _Opts) ->
    ?INFO_MSG("Hello there, ejabberd world!", []),
    ejabberd_hooks:add(filter_packet, global, ?MODULE, on_filter_packet, 0),
        ok.

stop(_Host) ->
    ?INFO_MSG("Bye bye, ejabberd world!", []),
    ejabberd_hooks:delete(filter_packet, global, ?MODULE, on_filter_packet, 0),
        ok.

on_filter_packet(drop) ->
    ?INFO_MSG("world - Message was dropped",[]),
    drop;
on_filter_packet({_From, _To, Xml} = Packet) ->
    % this clause never fires
    ?INFO_MSG("world - message hit clause", [Xml]),
    Packet;
on_filter_packet(Msg) ->
    % catch-all clause for non-message types
    ?INFO_MSG("world - message hit default", []),
    Msg.
```

When the module runs every packet triggers the catch-all clause so I know the hooks seem to be doing their job, and if I check the main ejabberd logs then messages are going through just fine.  If I remove the catch-all then the filter just crashes.

I've tried a number of variations of the filter clause taken from various examples (plus supporting code) e.g. :

```
{_From, _To, #xmlel{name = StanzaType}} = Input
```

or

```
{_From, _To, {xmlel, <<"message">>, _Attrs, Els} = _Packet} = _Msg
```

but none of them seem to be working.

I'm using two different Centos 7 set-ups (one with ejabberd installed as a package running on a physical box, the other using Vagrant with ejabberd installed from source) and a number of different XMPP clients, but the result is the same.  Ejabberd version is 17.07.31.

What obvious thing am I missing?